# Duplicate counts when trying to use two joins in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count, aggregate

I am fairly new to SQL and am wondering how to combine these two queries. Whenever I try to combine them the counts become the same. Basically my goal is to get the total career individual MVP wins and the total career shared MVP awards for each player.

```
SELECT p.nameLast, p.nameFirst, p.playerID, COUNT(asp.playerID) AS Shared_MVPs
FROM players AS p
JOIN awardsshareplayers AS asp ON asp.playerID = p.playerID
WHERE asp.awardID = 'MVP' 
GROUP BY  p.nameLast, p.nameFirst, p.playerID
ORDER BY p.nameLast

SELECT p.nameLast, p.nameFirst, p.playerID, COUNT(ap.playerID) AS Solo_MVPs
FROM players AS p
JOIN awardsplayers AS ap ON  ap.playerID = p.playerID
WHERE awardID LIKE '%MVP%' 
GROUP BY  p.nameLast, p.nameFirst, p.playerID
ORDER BY p.nameLast
```

Table Examples:

[image: Tables Examples(players, awardsshareplayers, awardsplayers):]

Comment: Helo MG1991, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, sql-server, postgres...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the aggregation in derived tables to avoid replicating rows in the `JOIN`s, using `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` to deal with players who have won Solo awards but not Shared and vice versa:

```
SELECT p.nameLast, p.nameFirst, p.playerID, 
       COALESCE(asp.Shared_MVPs, 0) AS Shared_MVPs, 
       COALESCE(ap.Solo_MVPs, 0) AS Solo_MVPs
FROM players AS p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT playerID, COUNT(*) AS Shared_MVPs
           FROM awardsshareplayers
           WHERE awardID = 'MVP'
           GROUP BY playerID) AS asp ON asp.playerID = p.playerID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT playerID, COUNT(*) AS Solo_MVPs
           FROM awardsplayers
           WHERE awardID LIKE '%MVP%'
           GROUP BY playerID) AS ap ON ap.playerID = p.playerID
ORDER BY p.nameLast
```